# Reference Request: Compendium of Hilbert Systems

Tags: reference-request, logic, first-order-logic, axioms

Is there a standard reference that contains, for some large family of logics, Hilbert Systems for those logics? I realize I can build them using, for example, the "mass production" technique outlined in Restall's book on substructural logics. But it would be nice if someone had already done some of this work and I were able to avoid doing some of it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [John Halleck's website](http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/logic/structures/systems/) for a lot of axiomatisations for (mainly) modal logics.

Comment: Great resource; thanks.